# How to use separate power source for Raspberry Pi + Arduino and motors as shown in the image below

Tags: arduino, batteries, dc-motor, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno

[image]

Is it possible to make this circuit?

I want to power the Raspberry Pi and Arduino with a powerbank and the motors with a separate battery through the driver module as the diagram shows. I used the same components as labeled in the diagram.

Comment: That would depend on the motor driver module. We have no clue which module you are using and how you intend to connect it so we cannot answer. Another thing is if the motor will ever run at all with a 9V battery, but it depends on the motor.

Comment: I am using a module L298 and a simple DC motor of 12V

Comment: We still don't know what kind of L298 modules you would be using. And how much current your motor uses. You have not said any of the relevant details, like which exact parts those are and what their detailed parameters are, so how can we answer if your 12V motor will even start when directly connected to 9V battery.

Comment: motor driver - https://rb.gy/aa6suy         motor - https://rb.gy/jrcv26

Comment: Is this a duplicate/repost of your previous question? Please don't start a new question but fix the old question.

Comment: I have given almost every detail about It, I think you haven't work on IoT

Comment: @Amit Nikhade Why do you require a raspberry pi and arduino combination to just control motor?

Comment: @AmitNikhade Those links to the motor and motor driver don't appear to work outside of India. Please [edit] the question to add the full links.

Comment: I am working on a project

Comment: The 9V battery still won't drive the motor.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do as you want.
Some points:

1. Do not use 9V battery to drive your motor! It doesn't provide enough current for motor (unless you driving very small motor).
2. To communicate between Raspberry and Arduino you may use any:

- USB,
- SPI
- I2C
- UART

3. Add a capacitor close to Arduino board, ideally 2 of caps. One of large capacity (provides some energy delivery when there is a dip in voltage due to motor draw) and another aound 100nF to protect from spikes.
   [image]
4. Ideally you power Raspberry and Arduino from this 5V power bank and L298/motor from one of this RC models battery.
   [image]

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick response and the modification of the diagram. Can you please tell me is the capacitor necessary over there.

Comment: Check the second picture: If you provide common power to RPi and Arduino, then you may not need capacitors.

Comment: @smajli Do mention about adding a flyback diode to the motor because you did not consider the safety of motor driver module.

Comment: @smajli you're really awesome men, Can you just elaborate on the motor driver connections i.e the connections to the pins of Arduino , battery, and the motor. Please.

Comment: @aditya Have you looked at the mentioned motor driver schematic? The pictured motor driver has all needed flyback diodes.

Comment: I appreciate your replies,   Can anyone can please tell me the connection to the motor driver module from Arduino,  Battery, and motors.

Comment: @smajli Comparing the 1st and second diagram I can see that in the second one you had directly connected the Arduino power source as the power bank and the communication between the RPI and Arduino through USB, can't we power and communicate just through the USB connection without adding any special connection for a power source to the Arduino

Comment: Yes, powering RPi from power bank and then powering Arduino (and communicating) through USB is possible.

Comment: @smajli please help me to make the connections to the driver module.

Comment: @AmitNikhade make some effort. This is not place to ask "Someone do all the job for me, please". To give you an easy start: https://lastminuteengineers.com/l298n-dc-stepper-driver-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: @smajli Thanks, by the way, I just asked you so that nothing wrong happens by my try and burn the circuit

Comment: @smajli Can the 12V battery harm raspberry pi in any way